# Возможно использовать LocalStorage в PhoneGap-приложении для хранения и передачи PHP факта авторизации?

Tags: php, cookie, phonegap, cordova, localstorage

В моём PhoneGap/Cordova мобильном приложении есть аля Личный кабинет пользователя. Нужно реализовать простую авторизацию (логин и пароль) для доступа к этому разделу. За серверную часть у меня полностью отвечает сайт на PHP.

Все пишут про преимущества LocalStorage перед COOKIE, но как же я могу использовать эту технологию для хранения факта авторизации пользователя на сервере, ведь в PHP переменные LocalStorage не доступны, а передавать с каждым запросом факт авторизации - это бред?

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage и Cookie несколько разные вещи. В контексте вашего вопроса, вы авторизуете пользователя по логин-паролю, а в куках передаете сессию, время жизни которой до закрытия браузера (приложения) или наступления таймаута.

Потом вы захотите, что бы ваше приложение запоминало пользователей и не требовало от них ввода логина-пароля при каждом запуске. Можно, после успешной авторизации, сохранить в куках некий долгоживущий токен, но гонять его туда-сюда при каждом запросе не есть хорошо.

Соответственно его надо где-то хранить и передавать в запросе, только когда сессия устарела, что бы сделать новую. Вот для этого и подходит LocalStorage. В нем вы храните токен (в самом простейшем случае там даже можно хранить логин-пароль, но это совсем не есть хорошо), который передается только для инициации сессии. Дальше все как обычно.

Comment: Хм. Я бы усомнился в том, что токен не нужно гонять. Если сервер stateless, то придётся. Если есть сессии, то можно, конечно, в сессию загонять токен.